# Check size of sun.misc.Queue

Tags: java, queue

My project is using a **Queue** by extending `sun.misc.Queue` and I need to know size of this queue every second.

As **sun.misc.Queue** does not provide `size` method API. I tried to add `toString` method to my **class** extending **sun.misc.queue**, and calling the toString in a seprate thread dedicated for printing the queue every second.

```
public String toString()
{
    int count = 0;
    Enumeration er = null;
    synchronized (this)
    {
        er = myQ.elements();

        while (er.hasMoreElements())
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return "" + count ;
}
```

**myQ** is field in this class.

But this ain't working too. After I add this code, complete system goes for toss.

Can anybody help in identifying if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Any reasons why you don't use one of the "official" jdk queues (which all have a `size` method)?

Comment: This code is around 5-6 years old, can't change the queue now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard java Queues (`LinkedList` for example is designed to be able to use it as a dequeue). They provide a size method.

Alternatively you could over-ride the various add/remove methods and keep a counter internally so you always know the size. You would be better off just using the right tool for the job though.

Comment: This code is around 5-6 years old, can't change the queue now. I had second option in mind, but thought of asking first, thought may be I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: do not use reflection unless you have to.

```
    Queue q = new Queue();
    Field f = Queue.class.getDeclaredField("length");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    int size = f.getInt(q);
    System.out.println(size);
```

I read your question again... now I'm mad at you for just writing "goes for toss". Stacktrace or GTFO.

Comment: By "goes for toss" I mean, system behavior is not as expected, and what is the behavior, that I can't explain here, because then I will have to explain domain.